# Python - Scrapy ecommerce website

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the price of this product

http://www.asos.com/au/fila/fila-vintage-plus-ringer-t-shirt-with-small-logo-in-green/prd/9065343?clr=green&SearchQuery=&cid=7616&gridcolumn=2&gridrow=1&gridsize=4&pge=1&pgesize=72&totalstyles=4699

With the following code but it returns an empty array

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="product-price"]/div/span[2]/text()').extract()
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because the site is dynamic(this is what I got when I use `view(response)` command in scrapy shell:
[image]
As you can see, the price info doesn't come out.

Solutions:
1. splash. 
2. selenium+phantomJS

It might help also by checking this answer:[Empty List From Scrapy When Using Xpath to Extract Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48738111/empty-list-from-scrapy-when-using-xpath-to-extract-values/48738528#48738528)

Answer (score 1):

The price is later added by the browser which renders the page using javascript code found in the html. If you disable javascript in your browser, you would notice that the page would look a bit different. Also, take a look at the page source, usually that's unaltered, to see that the tag you're looking for doesn't exist (yet).

Scrapy doesn't execute any javascript code. It receives the plain html and that's what you have to work with.

If you want to extract data from pages which look the same as in the browser, I recommend using an headless browser like Splash (if you're already using scrapy): https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash
You can programaticaly tell it to download your page, render it and select the data points you're interested in.

The other way is to check for the request made to the Asos API which asks for the product data. In your case, for this product:
http://www.asos.com/api/product/catalogue/v2/stockprice?productIds=9065343&currency=AUD&keyStoreDataversion=0ggz8b-4.1&store=AU

I got this url by taking a look at all the `XMLHttpRequest (XHR)` requests sent in the `Network` tab found in Developers Tools (on Google Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find JSON inside HTML (using regular expression) and parse it:

```
json_string = response.xpath('//script[contains(., "function (view) {")]/text()').re_first( r'view\(\'([^\']+)' )

data = json.loads(json_string)
price = data["price"]["current"]
```